# Problem with labelling tcolorboxes

Tags: tcolorbox

I have the following problem: using the `tcolorbox` package I get inconsistent results for the labelling: in this example I get that the boxes are both referred to as 1.1 :

[image]

The code for this is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{Mijnbox}[1]
{\stepcounter{table}%
\tcbset{breakable,coltitle=blue!20!black,colback=black!1!white,colframe=black!10!    white,title=Box ~\thetable: #1}
\begin{tcolorbox}}
{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\ref{Boxone} and \ref{Boxtwo}

\section{A try}
\begin{Mijnbox}{This one is called one}\label{Boxone}
I try to refer to this box 
\end{Mijnbox}

\begin{Mijnbox}{ge}\label{Boxtwo}
This is yet another box
\end{Mijnbox}
end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` package allows for automatic box numbering and using other counters as well. The label can be specified as an option.

It's quite useful to define a `\newtcolorbox` for such cases which get its own name space and does not interfere with other `tcolorbox` settings, which is 'polluted' by `\tcbset`.

- The other nice way with `\refstepcounter` was answered by [Torbjorn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) already, which is correct of course.
- I changed the colours for the screenshot only, but not in the displayed code

---

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox[use counter=table,number within=chapter]{MijnOtherBox}[2][]{breakable,coltitle=blue!20!black,colback=black!1!white,colframe=black!10!white,title={Box~\thetcbcounter: #2},#1}


\newenvironment{Mijnbox}[1]
{\stepcounter{table}%
  \tcbset{breakable,coltitle=blue!20!black,colback=black!1!white,colframe=black!10!    white,title=Box ~\thetable: #1}
  \begin{tcolorbox}}
  {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\ref{Boxone} and \ref{Boxtwo} and \ref{BoxThree}

\section{A try}
\begin{Mijnbox}{This one is called one}\label{Boxone}
I try to refer to this box 
\end{Mijnbox}

\begin{Mijnbox}{ge}\label{Boxtwo}
This is yet another box
\end{Mijnbox}

\begin{MijnOtherBox}[label=BoxThree]{This is box three}
Even another box
\end{MijnOtherBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need `\refstepcounter{table}` instead of `\stepcounter{table}`. The former will make the stepped counter the current/active one, which is picked up by `\label`.